# Pandas Xlsxwriter time format

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write out my pandas table using xlsxwriter. I have two columns:

```
Date       | Time  
10/10/2015  8:57
11/10/2015  10:23
```

But when I use xlsxwriter, the output is:

```
Date       | Time
10/10/2015  0.63575435
11/10/2015  0.33256774
```

I tried using datetime_format = 'hh:mm:ss' but this didn't change it. How else can I get the date to format correctly without effecting the date column?

Comment: What is the dtype of `Time` column? Can you post the output from `df.info()`

Comment: For both `Date` and `Time` column, they are non-null object.

Comment: So they are `str` and not `datetime`? If not post what I asked

Comment: Try using `engine='openpyxl'` when creating the writer or when calling `to_excel`.

Comment: The outputs are `Date                object` and `Date               5 non-null object` for dtypes and df.into() respectively

Comment: Have you looked into this: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_pandas_datetime.html  ?

Comment: Yes, I tried amending both datetime and date format but they only effected the `date` column and not the `time` column.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me, but there are some caveats. If the custom formatting will work depends on the Windows/Excel version you open it with. Excels custom formatting depends on the language settings of the Windows OS.

[Excel custom formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4)

[Windows date/time settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-dates-times-currency-measurements-display#1TC=windows-7)

So yeah, not the best solution... but the idea is to change the formatting for each column instead of changing how to interpret a type of data for the whole excel file that is being created.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some datetime data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date and time': [date(2015, 1, 1),
                                     date(2015, 1, 2),
                                     date(2015, 1, 3),
                                     date(2015, 1, 4),
                                     date(2015, 1, 5)],
                   'Time only':     ["11:30:55",
                                     "1:20:33",
                                    "11:10:00",
                                     "16:45:35",
                                    "12:10:15"],
                   })


df['Time only'] = df['Time only'].apply(pd.to_timedelta)
#df['Date and time'] = df['Date and time'].apply(pd.to_datetime)


# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
# Also set the default datetime and date formats.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_datetime.xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects in order to set the column
# widths, to make the dates clearer.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

#PLAY AROUND WITH THE NUM_FORMAT, IT DEPENDS ON YOUR WINDOWS AND EXCEL DATE/TIME SETTINGS WHAT WILL WORK
# Add some cell formats.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'd-mmm-yy'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': "h:mm:ss"})

# Set the format

worksheet.set_column('B:B', None, format1)

worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, format2)

worksheet.set_column('B:C', 20)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: The pandas dataframe errors  when I try to set it to timedelta or datetime ('TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()'). At least I've narrowed down where the issue is now - hopefully once I fix the pandas table then this will work.

Comment: This approach does not work for me on Microsoft Excel for Mac (latest pandas and xlsxwriter).